# Custom exe icon in Netbeans native package for Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to use my icon in native packaging for java Swing application.  There is no option for setting Application icon in properties. There is by default available for JavaFX applications. I need it for Swing having custom exe icon.

Inno setup is used for native packaging in netbeans 8.0.2.

Application icon is in Java Coffee cup icon. I can able to set the frame icon, but I need to set it for generating exe.

[My swing application icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/527Jc.jpg)

Comment: Swing doesn't generate a native executable for it's Jar's, you need to use a native wrapper instead, like exe4j

Comment: @MadProgrammer: when using "native packaging", NetBeans _does_ create an .exe wrapper.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Never used, always used a different wrapper

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have a number of reports with that application, Packing with exej4, doesn't launches any window, its size equals to jar only. I want to pack it as a whole application

Comment: So we're talking the difference between an executable for the program and an executable for the installer? I've used izPack (because it had Ant support) and exe4j to generate the output. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with the interaction between netbeans an inno so I can't really comment

Comment: @MadProgrammer   I'm new to izPack, suggest me some best tutorials to create installer for my gui application.

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR I just went through mostly the [documentation](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/IzPack+Home)

Answer (score 1):

My actual  configuration is Netbeans 8.01 with JDK 8 on windows 10
If you look inside your project, there is a subfolder **nbproject** that contains build directives. A close look at the file **build-native.xml** give you that:

```
if(isTrue(nativeEnabled) && defined(nativeType) && nativeType != "none") {
                var icon = new String(project.getProperty("deploy.icon.native"));
                if(defined(icon)) {
                    if(isTrue(fx_ant_api_1_2) && !isTrue(have_jdk_pre7u14)) {
                        var dicon = derelativizePath(icon);
                        // create temporary icon copy renamed to application name (required by native packager)
```

so you have to add a line in **YourProjectFolder/project.properties** and it must be like:
**deploy.icon.native=C:\\Path\\of\\the\\icon\\yourIcon.ico**
(path double slashed) 
After that you will be able to see the generated file with yourIcon provided.

Answer (score 0):

In your main Frame (In Navigation Window generally in the lower left) Click the JFrame to get the JFrame Options.

In the properties window (generally in the lower right) Go to Other Properties group->IconImage (Click the button (...) )

Choose custom code and there put something like:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/Image.png")).getImage()
```

Note that this image is in the classpath and is the path of the image in your JAR file.

So if you have the project package like `org.myPackage` in your directory `/home/user/Projects/myProj/org/myPackage`
You must have other directory `/home/user/Projects/myProj/resources/images/` with this image.